# How to test that an error is re-thrown in a catch statement with Jest

Tags: javascript, promise, jestjs

I have a function that returns a promise, but I want to test that it has a catch defined, and then additionally test that it re-throws the error.

This is a very contrived example but it was the clearest way to show the issue. In my actual code, I am calling a function that is mocked to fail (vs the manually rejecting in this example), and I have additional logging in the `catch` statement, which explains the re-throwing of the error.

```js
const foo = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject(new Error('reject')); // manually rejecting to mimic actual code...
  }).catch(error => {
    // do some additional logging...
    throw error;
  });
};

it('should catch and re-throw error', () => {
  // Received function did not throw
  // and
  // Unhandled promise rejection
  expect(() => foo()).toThrow();

  // Test passes, even when `throw error` is commented out with false positive
  expect(foo()).rejects.toThrow();
});
```

I can successfully check that the logging function is called, but can't figure out how to ensure the error is re-thrown after.

#### *WORKING* UPDATE :)

thanks to **@skyboyer** & **@Bergi** for getting me to think about the issue a bit differently, and exposing me to some of the finer points of jest

Below is both the updated code to show the logging function, and the updated tests i settled on.

The issues that led to this were

- unable to test `logging` was called due to the error being re-thrown
- unable to test the value of the error being re-thrown

Catching the rejected promise allowed me to do both.

I was going to leave in the `rejects.toEqual` test, but it seems redundant now...

interested in any feedback! and thanks again!

```js
// myModule.js
export const logging = () => {};
export const bar = () => new Promise(resolve => {});
export const foo = () => {
  return bar().catch(error => {
    logging();
    throw error;
  });
};

describe('myModule', () => {
  let fooReturn;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();

    jest.spyOn(myModule, 'bar').mockImplementation(() => {
      return Promise.reject({ error: 'bar error' });
    });

    jest.spyOn(myModule, 'logging').mockImplementation(() => {});

    fooReturn = myModule.foo();
  });

  it('should catch and re-throw error', () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    fooReturn.catch(result => expect(result).toEqual({ error: 'bar error' }));

    // removed since the above test covers that the promise was rejected
    // return fooReturn.rejects.toEqual(expect.anything());
  });

  it('should call the loggin method', async () => {
    expect.assertions(1);

    // prevents UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning
    fooReturn.catch(() => {});

    expect(myModule.logging).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "false positive"? .rejects is correct for a rejected promise, and your function under test _does_ throw the error so the positive test result is right.

Comment: updated to OP to be more clear. the false positive is even when `throw error` is commented out, it still passes

Answer (score 2):

You missed `return`.

https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#resolves--rejects

> Be sure to return the assertion—if you omit this return statement, your test will complete before the promise returned from fetchData is resolved and then() has a chance to execute the callback.

Your test should be

```
it('should catch and re-throw error', () => {
  return expect(foo()).rejects.toEqual(expect.anything());
});
```

As [u/Bergi noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71698970/how-to-test-that-an-error-is-re-thrown-in-a-catch-statement-with-jest/71699142?noredirect=1#comment126749779_71699142) with `async/await` it may look more laconic:

```
it('should catch and re-throw error', async () => {
  await expect(foo()).rejects.toEqual(expect.anything());
});
```

but if we miss to add `await` before our `expect` we will have exact the same issue as in version 1 without `return`. So beware.

Comment: jeez.... i can't believe that was all i was missing... ty!

Comment: strangely it only worked in my example code, but not in my actual code... im digging into it deeper... i replaced the api call with the exact `new Promise/reject` code from the example, that still isn't running as expected

Comment: that's weird, how about `return expect(Promise.reject(42)).rejects.toBe(42)`?

Comment: yea that works fine, but even with the example code, if i commented out the `throw error`, it would fail, but not with a jest error... it failed with a similar issue that i posted in the OP update (where it looks like a syntax error)

Comment: @brewster and what is error message then? I don't see it in the update

Comment: yea that's the strange part... there is no error message. it just fails with the ^ under that `expect` line. i added a screenshot of the test results

Comment: @brewster my fault, I missed that you were checking with `toThrow()` meantime with `rejects.` we should use value matchers instead like `toBe` for primitives or `toEqual` for object-ish values. Updated my answer, try with `.toEqual(expect.anything())`

Comment: `toThrow` is  only for cases when sync function throws exceptions

Comment: I would recommend to use `await`, not `return`, in front of `expect()`

Comment: @Bergi I agree, but its implicit `return <promise>` under the hood makes things even less obvious and more magic in this case. added to answer.

Comment: also I'm having 2 projects out of 12 with pretty close versions and configs, where `async/await` in tests leads to "Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout", meanwhile explicit `return <some Promise>` works fine.

Comment: ok! i found a working solution based on the feedback. i updated the OP with more detailed code, and the tests i landed on

Comment: the only thing i can't figure out is why i get the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`